# How do I input a js variable into a filter within ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have this:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in MediaFeedItems | filter: { category: 'userSelect' }" class="mediafeed--item">
```

This iterates through a list and filters out based on an attribute called 'category'. The filter is being selected by the user via drop down menu and the selection is being assigned to a variable 'userSelect' in the following function:

```
document.getElementById('category').addEventListener("change", function() {
    if(this.value == "HR") {
        this.userSelect = "HR";
    } else if (this.value == "Managers") {
        this.userSelect = "Managers";
    } else {
        this.userSelect = "Colleagues";
    }
});
```

How can I call that variable within the filter?

Comment: don't do this.  Angular won't know that there was a change based on an event listener like this.  The "Angular Way" is to use `ng-model`, or *if you must have a change event*, use `ng-change`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't think you need that function just put a ng model on your select and use it for your filter

```js
(function() {
    'use strict';
angular
  .module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', myCtrl);

   function myCtrl(){
       /* jshint validthis: true */
       var vm=this;
       vm.items = [
                   {category: 'cat1', text: 'one'},
                   {category: 'cat1', text: 'two'},
                   {category: 'cat2', text: 'three'},
                   {category: 'cat2', text: 'four'},
                   ];
   } 

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">
  <select name="singleSelect" ng-model="category">
      <option value="cat1">category 1</option>
      <option value="cat2">category 2</option>
    </select>
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="item in vm.items | filter: { category: category }">
            {{item.text }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```